# looping through subfolders in document library

Tags: powershell, csom

I have a document library and I want to loop through all the folders I have in it. I have this piece of code

```
           $Context.Load($List.RootFolder.Folders)
           $context.ExecuteQuery()
           ##write-host 'RootFolder.Folders.Count:', $list.RootFolder.Folders.Count
           foreach ($foldername in $list.RootFolder.Folders)
           {

               write-host $foldername.name 

           }
```

Which works for the folders in the root but not with subfolders. 
Also it returns a folder that is non existent called Forms, is this a oob folder that is hidden? How do I loop through subfolders as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to write a recursive method for this. You can exclude Forms folder as all the List & Libraries in SharePoint has a default Forms folder where all the view/Add/Edit forms will be stored.

```
function GetChildFolders($RootFolder) 
{
        $Context.Load($RootFolder)
        $Context.Load($RootFolder.Folders)
        $Context.ExecuteQuery()
        write-host $RootFolder.Name 
        foreach($folder in $RootFolder.Folders)
        {
          if($folder.Name -ne "Forms")
          {
           Recurse $folder  
          }
        }
}
```

Call this method and pass `$List.RootFolder`